# writing filenames with date last modified simultaneously in a separate file

Tags: python, python-3.x

for my project i wanted to store names of files present in a directory in a separate log file along with their last modified date.

I thought of method to first to append filenames in directory to `list1` and then append the modification date to `list2` and write both lists simultaneously to the log file? I just wanted to ask what of these is best method to do it or is there any other elegant way available? or is their any direct method available for this? thanks

Code to print 2 list simultaneously:

```
a=[file1,file2]
b=[date1,date2]

col_format = "{:<5}" * 2 + "\n"

with open("log.txt", 'w') as of:
    for x in zip(a, b):
        of.write(col_format.format(*x))
```

Comment: Why don't you store  datas in a single list? L=[ (file1,date1),(file2,date2)...]

Comment: @kantal can you advise me how should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary:

```
d = {file1: date1, file2: date2}

col_format = "{:<5}" * 2 + "\n"  

with open("log.txt", 'w') as of:
    for file in d:
        of.write(col_format.format(file, d[file]))
```

Or a single list using tuples (as @kantal suggested):

```
a = [(file1, date1), (file2, date2)]

col_format = "{:<5}" * 2 + "\n"  

with open("log.txt", 'w') as of:
    for tup in a:
        of.write(col_format.format(tup[0], tup[1]))
```

Or alternatively, simply write both name and date at the same time without storing them. something like:

```
col_format = "{:<5}" * 2 + "\n" 

with open("log.txt", 'w') as of:
    for file in os.listdir():
        of.write(col_format.format(file, os.path.getmtime(file))
```

Comment: getmtime returns in seconds since epoch. read here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time for some conversions.

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me too

this program writes filenames with date last modified into separate file

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

col_format = "{:<35}" * 2 + "\n"

with open("log.txt", 'w') as of:

    for file in os.listdir("path to directory"):
        mtime = os.path.getmtime(file)
        of.write(col_format.format(file, time.ctime(mtime)))
```